# VS Code Oracle Developer Tools - TLS Handshake failure

Tags: visual-studio-code, oracle-sqldeveloper, vscode-remote

My company uses a jumpbox to access an Oracle db.  I have installed the SSH-Remote extension in VS code and I can connect to the jumpbox.

On the jumpbox I can start a terminal window and type 'sqlplus user@tnsname' and then my password and I'm able to connect to the database.

I have installed the Oracle Developer Tools extension and configured the tns file path.  Everything seems to resolve correctly, but when I test the db connection by selecting Test, the UI reports:
TLS Handshake failure

I'm assuming there's some additional configuration that I need to do within VS Code, but I'm not sure where to start.

After more analysis, it appears that the underlying issue is:
IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Is VS Code doing more rigorous cert validation or is the cert store configured differently?

Answer (score 1):

The extension operates via Java still it would seem, so it carries it's own jdk (and thus it's own CACERTS)

```
C:\Users\<me>\.vscode\extensions\oracle.sql-developer-23.4.1-win32-x64\dbtools\jdk\lib\security\cacerts
```

Just import your signing root for the TLS connection into the cacerts above using keytool

```
keytool -importcert -keystore C:\Users\<me>\.vscode\extensions\oracle.sql-developer-23.4.1-win32-x64\dbtools\jdk\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -file .\hostroot.crt -alias 'db-tls-root'
```